# Why are static method reference types not supported in annotation members?

Tags: java, annotations

I would like to create my own DateTime validation annotation

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

@Constraint(validatedBy = DateTimeValidator.class)
public @interface DateTime {
    String message() default "{com.example.constraints.DateTime.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    TemporalQuery<?>[] queries() default {ZonedDateTime::from, LocalDateTime::from};
}

public class DateTimeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DateTime, String> {

    private DateTime dateTime;
    private TemporalQuery<?>[] queries;

    @Override
    public void initialize(DateTime dateTime) {
        queries = dateTime.queries();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        try {
            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parseBest(s, queries);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Is there any reason why the static method references cannot be supported in annotation types? What would be the best way to achieve my goal otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In short, because the *Language* forbids it.

The *Java Language Specification* makes a distinction in [JLS Chapter 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-9.html) between *normal interfaces* and *annotation types*.

While normal interfaces allow the standard *MethodHeader* and *MethodBody* productions, **by defintion** annotation type methods are much more restrictive.  Specifically, the values of an annotation are implemented as *virtual* methods, whose [return types are limited to](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1):

- primitives
- String
- Class
- Enum types
- other annotations (other than itself, or those that permit a circular path back to itself)
- Arrays of the above

Therefore, per the *language* specification, `javac` must generate a *compile-time error* if you attempt to use any other types.  The rationale for this language restriction comes from the practical limitations imposed by how annotation values are stored in bytecode.

When you place an annotation on an element, bytecode for the element must reference the value(s) without requiring access to any *other* classes. Specifically, all annotation values are really stored in the enclosing class *constant pool*.

The constant pool is used for many purposes, but it is a relatively simple data structure and it's not desirable to use it to encode complex data.  Usually entries are class names, method names, method signatures, etc.  The current way that annotation parameters are encoded in the pool *suggests* that a method handle would require, at a minimum, three(3) such entries for the above without considering the complexities of whether those methods are static, virtual, constructors, or from an interface. Do they involve generics? Etc.

### What you can do

As stated above, one of the *allowed* types is any Enum.  If the `TemporalQuery` implementations you wish to support can be limited to a fixed set *at compile-time*, then you can define an `enum` to contain a static member for each supported implementation and use it as a layer of indirection:

```
public enum TemporalQueryValidation {
    ZONED_DATE_TIME(ZoneDateTime::from),
    LOCAL_DATE_TIME(LocalDateTime::from),
    // ... more ...
    ;

    private final TemporalQuery<?> query;

    private TemporalQueryValidation (TemporalQuery<?> q) {
        this.query = q;
    }

    TemporalQuery<?> getQuery() {
        return query;
    }
}

@Constraint(validatedBy = DateTimeValidator.class)
public @interface DateTime {
    // ... other annotation values ...
    TemporalQueryValidation[] queries() default { ZONED_DATE_TIME, LOCAL_DATE_TIME };
}

public class DateTimeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DateTime, String> {

    private DateTime dateTime;
    private TemporalQuery<?>[] queries;

    @Override
    public void initialize(DateTime dateTime) {
        TemporalQueryValidation[] validations = dateTime.queries();
        queries = new TemporalQuery<?>[validations.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
            queries[i] = validations[i].getQuery();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        try {
            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parseBest(s, queries);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```